# C# XmlNodeList Extension IsNullOrEmpty Check

Tags: c#

I have an extension for IEnumerable collections like this:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
    return enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any(); 
}
```

It works for a lot of collections except for XmlNodeList.
Why is that? XmlNode implements IEnumerable ??

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because [`XmlNodeList` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx), you can use below instead:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this IEnumerable enumerable)
{
    return enumerable == null || !enumerable.Cast<object>().Any();
}
```

Comment: thanks! it works great, but why not use .Count() > 0 in stead of .Any() ? What's the difference?

Comment: @Ruutert: `Any()` get better performance because it just check whether list has item or not

Answer (score 1):

`XmlNodeList` only implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`, so you must have this method to get it done.

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this IEnumerable enumerable) {
    return enumerable == null || !enumerable.Cast<object>().Any();
}
```